# Can I transport a hairdryer in my hand luggage in Europe?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, prohibited-items

I am going to travel for Christmas and I would like to bring an hairdryer for a friend (yes, there are also hairdryers in the destination, but she likes this particular brand).

In principle there is no problem with it. At least it's not on the forbidden list, but I am afraid the hairdryer might have parts inside that, for some reason, are not allowed.

Can I transport a hairdryer in my hand luggage in European Union?

Comment: Unless the hair dryer is battery operated (I have yet to come across such a thing), you should have no problems at all. Enjoy your flight.

Comment: Europe is not a country.

Comment: @gerrit I am aware of that. But the rules are consistent enough and it makes more sense to have broad questions that may help other than asking if I travel from Cologne to La Coruna by plane can I bring an hair dryer.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Surprisingly (!!) [it does exist](http://www.amazon.com/Cordless-Dryer-2-battery-Freedryer-400watts/dp/B00MZVB1NM/).  It's hard for me to understand what it's good for though, given its low performance (400 W) and very short operating time (8-15 min). Maybe it's for use in cars where it would be possible to charge it slowly (low power), but it wouldn't be possible for draw 400 W (high power) from the car battery continuously.

Comment: @nsn However, it would make more sense to use the European Union here instead of Europe, because I think this is what you ment. The EU has roughly consistent rules, while also e.g. Russia, Turkey and Macedonia are (at least partly) part of Europe and have entirely different regulations.

Comment: @Szabolcs In the UK, bathrooms lack outlets, and if your only mirror is in the bathroom a battery-operated hairdryer would come in handy.

Comment: Depending on the airport, when you pass through security, it is likely your bag will be routed into the queue to be searched. You may wish to avoid the inconvenience by putting the dryer in hold luggage. However, there are no rules that would prevent you carrying a hair dryer.

Comment: On a techical note if you bring a hair dryer from outside EU to EU it probably won't work here safely.  The small plug adapters are for devices that support multiple voltages, they don't work for high power devices like drills, hairdryers, etc.

Comment: If we're doing weird types of hair dryers, there are also gas powered cordless ones, which are going to be a problem in hand luggage I suspect (gas cylinders). Mains powered hair dryers should not be an issue.

Comment: @JamesRyan there are travel hair dryers that can operate at different voltages.  There are also voltage transformers, though they are cumbersome.

Comment: @phoog and they don't work that well compared to a regular one because they are not tuned to be efficient at any of the specific voltages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[NIDirect](http://www.nidirect.gov.uk/dangerous-and-restricted-items-what-you-cannot-take-on-board-a-flight) (Northern Ireland government website) has a more specific list of some items, and in particular specify that you CAN indeed take a hairdryer, in both checked and hand luggage.

Answer (score 2):

Hairdriers are extremely common items likely to be carried by travellers, so carrying it should not be an issue. If there was a problem with them then we would know about it.

If you are bringing the item from outside the EU and it will be staying in the EU then you also have to consider customs. In the UK if it's worth less than £390 (£270 if arriving by private plane or boat) and it's for your own use or a gift then you are ok but if you are selling it to your friend then you would have to declare it to customs. I suspect the rules in the rest of the EU are very similar. Countries outside the EU may vary more.

Answer (score 1):

No problem - you can both put it in checked-in baggage or in carry-on luggage. It doesn't violate any regations whatsoever.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a link or source for this? It's useful to the OP and future users.

Comment: I've have a work experience in airport security. The regulations that apply to baggage are ICAO Forbidden items list (it's mainly a guideline, but airports are required to follow it) and IATA dangerous goods regulations, link provided: https://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Pages/dgr-guidance.aspx.  For the forbidden items list check any airport or airline homepge, they'll have a complete description in a user-friendly format.

Answer (score 0):

In some airports, if you have it in hand luggage, they will require you to unpack it for inspection. Manchester Airport, in particular, has lots of signs specifying this, but that's fairly standard for anything bigger than a phone charger with a plug nowadays.

Shouldn't be a problem though.